# Get symfony2 client based dynamic CSS working somehow

Tags: php, css, symfony

In my Symfony project, I have a bunch of clients, all having a couple colors.

My forms are setup with color pickers, everything is fine.

But how do I go about using these values in my CSS file, which is handled by assetic?

I've been searching Google, finding a lot of solutions for symfony1, bot not for symfony2.

Does anyone have an idea on a correct approach to this?

(ps: I cannot use LESS in this project)

Comment: Could you elaborate more? what do you mean with clients? are they logged in users? and in which context are these "couple colors" used?

Comment: a client is just an entity, to wich a logged in user is related,
the color values are saved in this entity, i have access to these across my controllers and templates,   but i have no idea how to get these processed into my css

Comment: basically my question is: how could i include an entity property, into a css file ..?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can, or i get you completely....but assuming you want to generate css colors, based on some property field, a user-entity has and is in a database-table, but if these colors are limited, for example user ranks, and each user rank has a color (say up to 20), then you can give every user-rank a special css-class, and have it shown.

Comment: the problem is, they are not pre-set,   a user can define his own 3 colors, to wich the color-scheme should adapt..  There must be SOME way of doing this, i can cant figure out how ...?

Comment: anybody have a clue ? im really stuck on this..   thx in advance

Comment: still noone..?,   this part of my project is still pending, and after all this time,  I still havent found a solution anywhere ..